# PyQt5 - Can I use different font sizes on different parts of the text in a label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I would like to have a label where I have text with parts where the sizes are different. Is this possible with PyQt5 or some CSS?

PS: I haven't coded it and am more looking for the theoretical answer than code so I can't provide any code or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QLabel supports a limited HTML subset, and basic styling is still enabled:

```
self.label.setText('''
    normalText 
    <span style="font-size: 18px">biggerText</span>
    <span style="font-size: 24px">veryBigText</span>
''')
```

Read more about the [Supported HTML Subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), which is valid for any rich-text enabled widgets (QLabel and all widgets that use a QTextDocument, like all QTextEdit descendants).